# Deuce - The One, homophobic?

Tags: lyrics, meaning

I ve recently dicovered the song [Deuce - The One](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vm-asWH4UFo), which I really liked the melody and refrain.

As with each song I like, I searched for the lyrics to understand what the song was really about, and am disturbed by one part of it:

> I see the sickness in the signs
>
> The dead weight in line
>
> **Like the sickness in my mind**
>
> **Homosexuals** and liars
>
> Fuck playing for reasons
>
> Fuck playing for Jesus

Strangely, I couldn't find comment or discussion about this song's lyrics about that part, only about if it is a Hollywood Undead song or whatever.

My question is: Is this part of the lyrics indicate that Deuce is homophobic? If not, why is the reference there, and what's it's meaning?

Comment: As he wears a t-shirt with "LA PRIDE" written on it in the clip, cat40's interpretation seems to go in the same direction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you have it exactly backwards. I think the song is about a person who is on the receiving of homophobia. The song seems to be about a homosexual/bisexual male who is upset that he is not accepted because of it, particularly by the Christian church ([The Catholic church has delcared homosexuality a mortal sin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortal_sin#Mortal_sins); I'm not sure what other Christian denominations have to say about it off the top of my head). Here's a line by line analysis of the song, if you're interested:

> I'm supposed to be the one who brings us all together
>   Weak or strong, not just a song
>   We sing along when things go wrong
>   You will need me when you fall
>   And I will need you when I'm wrong
>   Tears lead me on
>   They let me lead you so far
>   Weak or strong, I'll hold your arm

Here, the singer acknowledges the fact that he is a musician, and thus people will turn to his music when they are feeling upset. I'm not sure what the last half means.

The lines "f*** playing for Jesus" and "I'll burn a hole through your cross" suggest a dissatisfaction with religion. The lines

> My soul's already lost
>   And it's funny 'cause they're saying 'He's hot'
>   But they don't see the fucking tears that I've cried
>   And they don't hear me when I scream when I die
>   I wanna live good, I wanna live right
>   My insecurities are eatin' me alive

suggest that the singer is homosexual. The last two lines suggest that the singer is upset that he is homosexual, because parents/churches/society tend to say that being homosexual or bisexual is "wrong", and being heterosexual is "right", and feels that he is somehow living "wrong".

> I need a friend, someone close to my heart
>   That'll help me through my struggles
>   You can help me through my times

I believe here and here:

>
Don't think I'm broken, 'cause I'm not
Got milk? Got problems?
Problems is all that I got
You're looking down on a barrel of a bent pole
Take my hand, I promise that I'll go slow
When you looked too close you end up with a broke soul
'Cause in the end it's certain where all the souls go
Maybe you can show me how to live right
And come see how it all ends wrong

The singer is looking for a boyfriend

These lines (not in sequence)

> Already found the devil, he's my best friend
>
> The bible keeps telling me 'Don't go!'
>
> 'Cause in the end it's certain where all the souls go

further the theory that the singer is dissatisfied with religion. Homosexuality is often considered to be a sin, and is therefore "the work of the devil". The singer believes that homosexuality is *not* a sin (and I personally agree), and therefore he will not go to hell for it. The last line here even suggests that the singer believes everyone goes to heaven, hell, or no-where, but they all go to the same place

> I want a pill for every bad thought
>   For every chick I f***ed
>   For every time I lost

The singer seems to be contemplating suicide (I'm guessing the pills refer to sedatives/sleeping pills, a common suicide method"), and feels that he has "lost" and become untrue to himself by engaging in sexual intercourse with females.

**On a side note:** Just because someone sings something doesn't mean that they necessarily mean it or believe in the message. For an extreme example of this, check out Eric Bogle's ["Bloody Rotten Audience"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wAhpwc19nM4)

**A second note:** I'm not sure if you know this, but the word "homosexual" is not in itself offensive. If that's what you're worried about, worry no longer. Disclaimer on this note: I am not homosexual and have a known hatred of euphemisms

Comment: I knew "homosexual" is not in itself offensive, but when reading the lyrics, as a non native reader, I had trouble separating when he is talking himself, or for thoses he criticized. I am happy to be proven wrong, and greatly appreciate your analysis :)

Answer (score 1):

Deuce isn't against gay people because if you look at the words below, he talks about "fuck playing for Jesus". If you remember, the Bible states that being gay is a sin. He looks at it like if you're gay, you aren't playing for Jesus so "fuck" him. Look at the line "Homosexuals and liars". He is talking about those who judge and won't come out themselves. One must examine all of the lines as a whole, without taking part of it out of context.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if he's homophobic,but considering how the song seems to be written to HU about him being kicked out, (I'm not going to bothering explaining that one; it's a popular theory) I don't think the song is about him being gay or bi. There is a rumor on the internet that Johnny Three Tears is gay or bi, and since he is a member of HU that has openly stated he's happy Deuce was kicked out, that may be Deuce either trying to pick on J3T or fuel the rumor that he's gay.
All his talk (rap?) about "fuck Christianity" could be attributing to the fact that HU is pretty religious, and mentions "the good book" "judgement day" and "Holy Ghost, hold me close" in many of their songs. I think it is quite possible that behind closed doors, raising morale with "we're doing this for God," might have been said, so when Deuce got kicked out he was picking on the beliefs of the remaining HU members.

tl;dr, I don't think he's homophobic, I think he's trying to suggest Hollywood Undead is gay, because let's be honest, he's obviously bitter.